Visual Studio Debugger Visualizer Work's Only For One Object
I create my Debugger Visualizer for Visual Studio 2022 Community and I find out that Visual Studio can visualize only one object at a time. Is there a way to make Visual Studio Visualizer track more than one object of same type?
Or maybe something wrong with my Visual Studio? Maybe exists some magic property somewhere?
Example:
Here is example:

As you can see, here two variables 'a' and 'b' (same type of 'string') and only one Text Visualizer. And I need to have two Visualizer for both 'a' and 'b'.

From reading this doc, looks like Debugger visualizers are accessible when hovering over a variable.  What do you mean it visualize multiple object at a time? Could you please provide a detailed screenshot to help me better understand your scenario?

added comment and pic, as you can see - you can't open two toolwindow (visualizer) for two variables of the same type at the same time

The Text Visualizer behaves different at my side. I need one Visualizer  for  both a and b(same type). The Visualizer will detect the current selected variable and update the display. Please check https://i.sstatic.net/GPdefZxQ.gif.
Did you follow this guide to create Debugger Visualizer?

Yes,i have read this guide and on your video you also can see that you couldn't open two ToolWindow(Text Visualizer) for two variables(same type) simultaneously.
You only can open one toolwindow. If you hovering over first variable VS open's one toolwindow and if you hover over second variable(same type)
your window just redrawing itself and i want VS to open me second ToolWindow(Text Visualizer).

Okay, i see. Based on my test, built-in visualizers(Text  Visualizer) can open only one ToolWindow for same type variables at a time by default. Not sure if it's supported to customize to meet your need. If possible, could you please your sample code to help me investigate further?

I add some addition

Glad to hear that you have found a solution of this issue. If possible, you could add it as an answer. This will help other users who has the same issue . Just a reminder.;)

Now we know that for the same type, Visual Studio reopens the same toolwindow.
I figured out that, when you create your Debugger Visualizer you need to specify DebuggerVisualizerProviderConfiguration constructor and this constructor takes objects of class VisualizerTargetType.
You can specify same type .NET type (on image below, you can see that I specify 'string') but different titles ((1) through (4)) and Visual Studio will open individual tool windows when you click on 'View'.
public override DebuggerVisualizerProviderConfiguration DebuggerVisualizerProviderConfiguration => new(
    new VisualizerTargetViewType("My Visualizer 5.1 (1)", typeof(string)),
    new VisualizerTargetViewType("My Visualizer 5.1 (2)", typeof(string)),
    new VisualizerTargetViewType("My Visualizer 5.1 (3)", typeof(string)),
    new VisualizerTargetViewType("My Visualizer 5.1 (4)", typeof(string)))
{
    Style = VisualizerStyle.ToolWindow

